# Android How to Convert Json Array in String Array

Tags: android, json

This is my JSON array data

```
{"data":"{'Class1','class2'}","success":"1"}
```

How do I convert this to a string array?

Comment: its not `JSONArray`  it `JSONObject`

Answer (score 0):

JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray("json string");

But your json is not an array, array's in json are with [ ]